# Powershell HTML message inline images

Tags: email, powershell, message, sendmessage, bulk

i was trying to make a bulk email send using Powershell, however i'm not able to use the code to use images inside the code (inlineattachments), it says that the command is not recognize. is there any way to create a HTML document and send it by mail from PS with the in line images?

Comment: Which command is not recognized? Show your code + the actual error message

Comment: i used several method, but i'm currently triying this one https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Send-MailMessage-3a920a6d

the error i get its: "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'InlineAttachments"

Answer (score 0):

-`InilineAttachments` parameter won't be present in `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet which is from Module `Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility` , You have to download the script Send-MailMessage.ps1 , Dot source it `. \Send-MaiMessage` then use the new function.

Regards,

kvprasoon